# Streamlit: customizing values in sidebar.selectbox()

Tags: streamlit

Is there a way to show a name alias in the streamlit `st.sidebar.selectbox()`?

So for example:

```py
raw_names = st.sidebar.selectbox(
    'Name:', get_name_list(), key='port'
)
    
def get_name_list() -> list:
    return ("Name A" ==  "A949", "Name B" ==  "B384")
```

And then, what is used for raw_names is only the second element of the list (so "A949" or "B384").

I have done this in a shiny app but not sure if possible with Streamlit as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `format_func` argument of [`selectbox`](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/widgets/st.selectbox).

> `format_func`
>
> Function to modify the display of the labels. It receives the option
> as an argument and its output will be cast to str.
>
> Source: [the Streamlit documentation.](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/widgets/st.selectbox)

You can use it like this:

```py
import streamlit as st

d_convert = {
    "A949": "Name A",
    "B384": "Name B",
}

def convert_option(opt):
    return d_convert[opt]

raw_name = st.sidebar.selectbox(
    'Name:', d_convert.keys(), key='port', format_func=convert_option
)

st.write(f"You chose {raw_name}")
```

It gives:

[image: Name B is displayed in the selectbox and B384 on the displayed text]